# Apache RewriteRule works under http not under https

Tags: php, apache, ssl, centos, redhat

I have a Apache RewriteRule which works under http within httpd.conf but not under https within ssl.conf

I receive a 500:Internal Server Error when navigating to that file under https but i see the redirect when I use http.

DocumentRoot is /var/www/html

I am trying to redirect any requests to /var/www/html/site/testfile.js to /var/www/html/site/test.php. This totally works under http like so:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
     RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/site/testfile.js(\?.*)?$ /site/test.php$1 [P]
    </VirtualHost>`

Under ssl.conf it is set like so:

```
`<VirtualHost _default_:443>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/site/testfile.js(\?.*)?$ /site/test.php$1 [P]
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel debug
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2  
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/star_domainname_ca.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>`
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

For some reason logging access.log and ssl_access log are not writing either.. nothing in the error logs which could explain why this is not working.

Comment: unless you want to supprt IE<v5 remove the setenvIf instructions.

Comment: Thanks! that might help.

Comment: For Some reason my error log doesn't display any errors regarding to this... also my access log and ssl_access log are empty for some reason. I wish i could see the log for these too

Comment: If you use 301 redirect instead of 302 redirect the browser keep the answer in an internal cache, so no new requests. Enforce temporary redirect whil testing it.

Answer (score 0):

solved this by changing the rewrite rule to the following under SSl.conf

RewriteRule ^/site/testfile.js(\?.*)?$ /site/test.php$1 [L]